# "Sorry, something went wrong" on content search web part for users with Read permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, search, administration, content-search-web-part

I have the following:-

1. Team site collection with publishing features enabled.
2. Inside the Team site collection home page I added **multiple** content search web parts (6 content search web parts).
3. When users with Edit or Contribute permission access the home page they can view the content search web-parts without any problems.
4. When users with Read permission, access the page they will get the following error, one each of the 6 content search web parts:

[image]

If I grant this user Edit permission then he can view the webpart, and if I grant him Read permission back the problem will occur again. also I have noted that when users with Read permission do a hard refresh for the browser "CTRL + F5" they can view the results, but if they navigate back to the page, they will receive the same error?

Here is the logs, where the page which will show the error is `http://www.tgroup.intra:80/my%20dash/SitePages/Home.asp`x:

```
10/18/2016 18:50:47.02  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x2660  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           amge7   Medium      SPFederationAuthenticationModule.IsRedirectToLogOnPage: Detected a redirection but the redirect is not to a known signin page: http://www.tgroup.intra/my dash/SitePages/Home.aspx  79b1ae9d-0cce-c0b7-30fc-0e3f1815a827
10/18/2016 18:50:47.02  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x1590  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7v   Medium      Reverse mapping URI from 'http://www.tgroup.intra/my dash/SitePages/Home.aspx' to 'http://www.tgroup.intra/my%20dash/SitePages/Home.aspx'   79b1ae9d-0cce-c0b7-30fc-0e3f1815a827
10/18/2016 18:50:47.02  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x1590  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,0 adc7u,16 adc7v   79b1ae9d-0cce-c0b7-30fc-0e3f1815a827
10/18/2016 18:50:47.02  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x1590  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra/my dash)). Execution Time=18.1161292845878    79b1ae9d-0cce-c0b7-30fc-0e3f1815a827
10/18/2016 18:50:47.02  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x1590  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           amge7   Medium      SPFederationAuthenticationModule.IsRedirectToLogOnPage: Detected a redirection but the redirect is not to a known signin page: http://www.tgroup.intra/my%20dash/SitePages/Home.aspx    79b1ae9d-0cce-c0b7-30fc-0e3f1815a827
10/18/2016 18:50:47.14  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x11DC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra/my dash/SitePages/Home.aspx)). Parent No  
10/18/2016 18:50:47.14  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x11DC  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra/my dash/SitePages/Home.aspx)  79b1ae9d-ccd6-c0b7-30fc-0cc9c8b54620
10/18/2016 18:50:47.14  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x11DC  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              adc7u   Medium      Mapping URI from 'http://www.tgroup.intra:80/my%20dash/SitePages/Home.aspx' to 'http://sps01/my%20dash/SitePages/Home.aspx' 79b1ae9d-ccd6-c0b7-30fc-0cc9c8b54620
10/18/2016 18:50:47.14  w3wp.exe (0x23F0)                           0x4720  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://www.tgroup.intra:80/my%20dash/SitePages/Home.aspx)). Parent No
```

Also these logs which contain the word error:

```
10/18/2016 18:50:47.33  NodeRunnerQuery1-9004fabc-2086- (0x1268)    0x4B08  Search                          Query Processing                aizgn   Medium      Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineHardWiredFlowExecutor : (FlowExecutor)eventSearchFlowDone: 9004fabc-2086-478e-8581-605309dd8161, , Microsoft.ProductivitySearchFlow, 35,  Error= 874f4e09-3109-480d-aa95-5a33d9619907  874f4e09-3109-480d-aa95-5a33d9619907
10/18/2016 18:50:47.35  NodeRunnerQuery1-9004fabc-2086- (0x1268)    0x2AFC  Search                          Query Processing                aizgn   Medium      Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineHardWiredFlowExecutor : (FlowExecutor)eventSearchFlowDone: 9004fabc-2086-478e-8581-605309dd8161, , Microsoft.ProductivitySearchFlow, 47,  Error= 4d643631-bd5d-4843-b3a0-23c9818682b9  4d643631-bd5d-4843-b3a0-23c9818682b9
10/18/2016 18:50:47.36  NodeRunnerQuery1-9004fabc-2086- (0x1268)    0x2744  Search                          Query Processing                aizgn   Medium      Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineHardWiredFlowExecutor : (FlowExecutor)eventSearchFlowDone: 9004fabc-2086-478e-8581-605309dd8161, , Microsoft.ProductivitySearchFlow, 66,  Error= af0a51bd-7d11-473d-88c5-eb4fa63dcf2d  af0a51bd-7d11-473d-88c5-eb4fa63dcf2d
```

Can anyone advise me on this please?

**EDIT**
After hours of investigation i try changing the Loading Behavior for the content search web part from "*Sync option: Issue query from the server.* " to "*Async option: Issue query from the browser*". and the error is almost done. it will appear but in very less frequent !!

So now i am totally confused on the relation between; The Loading Behavior & READ/EDIT permission & the "Sorry, something went wrong"  Error??

Comment: Have you configured the Object Cache accounts? These are used in publishing sites to aid with building the search index for users with edit and users with read-only access. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although this may be dated it may help someone else.

Figure the display template in use and check if the file is in draft/unpublished/unapproved mode. If so Publish/approve it.
See if this fixes the issue

**Detailed**
Edit Page > CSWP > Edit > Display Template - Note item name
Navigate to Site Settings > Design Manager > Edit Display Templates > locate file in use